# How to write in specific cell in a CSV file?

Tags: java, csv, apache-commons-csv

I need to write in a specific cell in a `.csv` file with `org.apache.commons.csv` library whitout iterate and copy all lines.

I tried this:

```
Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(Properties.dataFilePath));
CSVParser csvParser = new CSVParser(reader, CSVFormat.DEFAULT);
List<CSVRecord> records = csvParser.getRecords();
records.get(rowNumber)[columnIndex] = value;
```

However it is not allowed.

**Edit 1**

My IDE mentioned : `The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to CSVRecord`

Comment: Can you please share the concrete error message?

Comment: I updated my question with the message.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried it with
`value = records.get(rowNumber).get(columnIndex);`?

Have a look here, it may help you: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVRecord.html

Comment: Yes but I'm not able to set something with `get` method.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your first try not correctly.

Comment: You can't override the value in a CVSRecord, it's only for reading.
If you want to change content of your CSV-File, you have to read with CSVRecoed the content of your file, modify it and then you have to write it with CSVPrinter to your new file.

Read: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/user-guide.html#Example:_Parsing_an_Excel_CSV_File
Print: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/user-guide.html#Printing_with_headers